# Why does "npm install" in a package ignore "bin" in the top-level package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a node package whose entire purpose is to install a CLI script.  For testing purposes, I would like to be able to run the script out of `node_modules/.bin`.  However, `npm install` ignores "bin" in the top-level package.json, and looking at the code, this appears to be intentional:

```
function linkBins (pkg, folder, parent, gtop, cb) {
  if (!pkg.bin || !gtop && path.basename(parent) !== "node_modules") {
    return cb()
  }
```

The condition `!gtop && path.basename(parent) !== "node_modules"` will be true exactly when one is running `npm install` without `-g` and it's processing the top-level package.

Why does it do this?  How is one supposed to test one's CLI scripts without installing them globally?

Comment: Isn't running your script by `node script.js` (or `./script.js` for that matter) enough to test it?

Comment: @ralphtheninja My test framework has to know to do that instead of just setting $PATH.  It's not a huge thing, but it is a thing.

Comment: I don't know why, but I'd like to thank you for finding this. I just spent so much time trying to figure out why "bin" wasn't working as documented. :(

Comment: I've created a bug for this. It's still present 3+ years later. :p
https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3488